# Given 3 events, $S_1$, $S_2$, $S_3$, how do I express $((S_1 \cup S_2) \cap (S_2 \cup S_3) \cap (S_3 \cup S_1))$ more concisely?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have three events: $S_1$, $S_2$, $S_3$. Is there a way to express $((S_1 \cup S_2) \cap (S_2 \cup S_3) \cap (S_3 \cup S_1))$ in a simpler manner?

Comment: @zkutch You are wrong. Any point that belongs to two of the sets belongs to this intersection.

Comment: I agree with Kavi Rama Murthy's comment and I don't see how the OP can be more succinct.  The set represents all points that are in **at least** two of the three sets $S_1, S_2, S_3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

zkutch's claim isn't quite right. If you draw the Venn diagram, you get:

[image]

Which is not the same as $A\cap B\cap C$. I guess you can also express your event as $$(S_1\cap S_2)\cup(S_2\cap S_3)\cup(S_3\cap S_1)$$
but this isn't really simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If by 'more concisely' you meam 'fewer symbols', here's an equivalent expression that uses $15$. It does however, use the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) operation to achieve this concision, which you might regard as cheating!
$$((S_1 \triangle S_2) \cap S_3) \cup (S_1 \cap S_2)$$

Also, it's not unique: any permutation of the indices gives the same set.